# Merge 2 different Google my Business accounts with 2 different locations for same company

Tags: google-maps, google-my-business, accounts

I have for a client 2 different GMB accounts, 2 different locations since it has 2 shops but I want to merge these accounts since they belong to the same brand name.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Google My Business only supports merging of duplicate accounts and not locations, therefore you will need to go ahead and delete one. Then you simply attach another location to the main GMB account, it'll send a postcode out where you will need to verify the address again.

Comment: And for attaching another location I have to use exactly the same company name?

Comment: An address doesn't include a company name therefore there is no database Google can use to verify if true or false.